# Is there a method to display accuracy scores for each and every model which are inside a VotingClassifier object?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, precision-recall, ensemble-learning

My question is about ensemble learning.
I am a beginner in ML field and wondering whether there exists a way to print all the metrics(such as accuracy) for each and every ML algorithm inside the Voting Classifier object seen below.
What I mean is an output I have written in bold:

**- lr_model accuracy => 0.70**

**- lgb_model accuracy => 0.72**

**- xgb_model accuracy => 0.71**

```
 lr_model=LogisticRegression()
 lgb_model=lgb.LGBMClassifier()
 xgb_model=xgb.XGBClassifier()
 model=VotingClassifier(estimators=[("lr",lr_model), ("lgbm",lgb_model), 
 ("xgb",xgb_model)],voting='soft')
 model.fit(X,y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could access fitted sub-estimators of model by `model.named_estimators_.{name}`. for example:

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

y_pred = model.named_estimators_.lr.predict(x)
lr_accuracy=accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred)
```

Also, [model.transform(X)](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/844b4be24/sklearn/ensemble/_voting.py#L386) return "probabilities per label" or "predicted label" of each classifier for all X, make it easy to compute any metrics for each classifier.